# Virtual Host on subdomain only on TomCat httpd.config

Tags: apache, tomcat, httpd.conf

I have a virtual host

```
<VirtualHost *:80> 
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyRequests Off
  ServerName gms.example.co
  ProxyPass / http://localhost:9081/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:9081/
</VirtualHost>
```

That picks up all http requests i.e. both gms.example.co and example.co get forwarded to localhost:9081

How do I only forward gms.example.co to localhost:9081 and example.co to localhost ?

**EDIT**

```
<VirtualHost *:80> 
  ServerName example.co
  DocumentRoot C:/workspace/html/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80> 
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyRequests Off
  ServerName gms.example.co
 ProxyPass / http://localhost:9081/
 ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:9081/
</VirtualHost>
```

At the end of httpd proxy.

The second works, the first one doesn't.

> Internal Server Error

I also get this on localhost so I assume they're related

And this error in the logs

```
[Tue Sep 13 19:38:38.081314 2016] [core:alert] [pid 24988:tid 1112] [client 127.0.0.1:60053] C:/workspace/html/.htaccess: Unrecognized header format %
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create another VHost configuration, with the `ServerName` directive set to `example.co` or `www.example.co`. In your server's root config file, `Include` the newly created VHost config too.

```
<VirtualHost *:80> 
  ServerName example.co
  ServerAlias www.example.co
  DocumentRoot /path/to/your/localhost
</VirtualHost>
```

save the above as `000-root.conf` (the `000` is so that this gets higher precedence).

Comment: Currently I've just got this straight in the httpd.conf, will this only work if they are seperate files?

Comment: @user5839 Put the above rule just before your virtualhost config.

Comment: getting close I've got an Internal Server Error on the example.co and but the gms.example.co is working as it should. I'll keep playing. Looks like the right answer.

Comment: It's close but not there yet - anything else to suggest?

Comment: ht access was the problem - this fixed it